# Overwriting dependency/plugin Management in multiple Levels of POMs

Tags: java, maven, maven-3

I am working in a Maven environment that has a 3-level structure.:

> Maven Project POM Structure
>   Company POM
>   - - Project POM
>   - - - - Module 1 POM
>   - - - - Module ... POM

The company POM defines both dependencyManagment & pluginManagement. These defaults are maintained at a company level. In the Project POM I want to overwrie certain defaults from the project POM and have it leveraged over all of my modules.

Question: 
**Is there a way to leverage the settings of dependencyManagement & pluginManagement in the project POM over the company one?**

In case I need to elaborate my question or provide more information, please guide me accordingly!

The 'Project POM' ->  refers to the Company POM.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
     xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
     xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

<parent>
    <groupId>com.company</groupId>
    <artifactId>company-pom</artifactId>
    <version>6.0.2</version>
</parent>

<groupId>com.project</groupId>
<artifactId>project</artifactId>
<version>1.0.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
<packaging>pom</packaging>

<!-- Properties -->
<properties>
    <!-- Settings -->
    <java.version>11</java.version>
    <maven.version>3.6.0</maven.version>

    <!-- Project Configuration -->
    <project.encoding>UTF-8</project.encoding>
    <project.gitlab.connection>...</project.gitlab.connection>
    <project.artifactory.releases>...</project.artifactory.releases>
    <project.artifactory.snapshots>...</project.artifactory.snapshots>

    <!-- Version Control -->
    <spring.version>5.1.3.RELEASE</spring.version>
    <spring-boot.version>2.1.1.RELEASE</spring-boot.version>

</properties>

<!-- Source Control Management -->
<scm>
    <connection>scm:git:${project.gitlab.connection}</connection>
    <developerConnection>scm:git:${project.gitlab.connection}</developerConnection>
    <tag>HEAD</tag>
</scm>

<!-- Distribution Management -->
<distributionManagement>
    <repository>
        <id>artifactory</id>
        <url>${project.artifactory.releases}</url>
    </repository>
    <snapshotRepository>
        <id>artifactory</id>
        <url>${project.artifactory.snapshots}</url>
    </snapshotRepository>
</distributionManagement>

<!-- Local Dependencies -->
<!-- Project Dependencies -->
<dependencyManagement>
    <dependencies>
        <!-- Spring Dependency Management -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-framework-bom</artifactId>
            <version>${spring.version}</version>
            <type>pom</type>
            <scope>import</scope>
        </dependency>
        <!-- Spring Boot Dependency Management -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-dependencies</artifactId>
            <version>${spring-boot.version}</version>
            <type>pom</type>
            <scope>import</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
</dependencyManagement>

<build>
    <!-- Local Plugins -->

    <!-- Project Plugins -->
    <pluginManagement>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.8.0</version>
                <configuration>
                    <release>${java.version}</release>
                    <encoding>${project.encoding}</encoding>
                </configuration>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>default</id>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>compile</goal>
                            <goal>testCompile</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-enforcer-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.0.0-M2</version>
                <configuration>
                    <rules>
                        <requireJavaVersion>
                            <version>${java.version}</version>
                        </requireJavaVersion>
                        <requireMavenVersion>
                            <version>${maven.version}</version>
                        </requireMavenVersion>
                    </rules>
                </configuration>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>default</id>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>enforce</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </pluginManagement>
</build>

<modules>
    <module>module1</module>
    <module>module2</module>
</modules>

</project>
```

The Module POM in which I want to use the versions of plugins / spring specified in the company POM.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <parent>
        <groupId>com.project</groupId>
        <artifactId>project</artifactId>
        <version>1.0.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    </parent>

    <artifactId>module1</artifactId>
    <packaging>jar</packaging>    

    <dependencies>
        <!-- Dependencies - Spring -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <!-- Dependencies - Application -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.javamoney</groupId>
            <artifactId>moneta</artifactId>
            <version>1.3</version>
            <type>pom</type>
        </dependency>
        <!-- Dependencies - Test -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <!-- Local Plugins -->
        <plugins>

            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-enforcer-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.8.0</version>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
                <artifactId>versions-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.7</version>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
        <!-- Global Plugins -->
    </build>

</project>
```

Comment: You can of course overwrite anything via pluginManagement or dependencyManagement in your own project...but I would always reconsider why you need to overwrite things...

Comment: The company POM defines a lot of versions and default settings. For my purpose I would like to update some versions to the latest. But I can't find a way to actually overwrite it. The pluginManagement / dependencyManagement sections in the Project POM seem to be overwritten by the Company POM. 

Only by specifically adding them as a dependency / plugin am I able to overwrite them in the child modules of the project.

Comment: you can simply define the pluginManagement and define a newer versions of plugins ? Maybe It would be best to show an example of your pom files...

Comment: I am unable to change the 'company' POM as this is not maintained by me. I inherit it, and I can overwrite it explicitely. My question is if I can leverage the specifics of dependencyManagement / pluginManagement in the Project POM and use that in the child modules over the ones of the company. (At the moment unless explicitly stated, it reverts to the Company POM)

I will add examples to my question.

Comment: For example the Company POM states for Enforcer => Version 1.4, I state in the project POM version 3.0.0-M2, yet the chuld pom unless explecitly told the version doesn't use the specified version in pluginManagement.

Comment: Your company pom does not define the distributionManagement correctly? Your company pom does not define encoding to be UTF-8 ? Encoding should be defined see [FAQ](https://maven.apache.org/general.html#encoding-warning) furthermore you should never add and execution block for plugins which are already bound to the life cycle...maven-compiler-plugin is part of the lifecyle only define it's version...furthermore If you use spring-boot in a project you should define spring framework separately cause spring Boot already contains the correct version to be used...etc. ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Question: Is there a way to leverage the settings of dependencyManagement & pluginManagement in the project POM over the company one?

**Can you do this?** Yes, by actually specifying both dependency/plugin management as well as the actual  /  to overwrite to parent settings.

**Should you do this?** No it makes for a very 'unclean' approach to POM management and defies the logic of dependencyManagement & pluginManagement being used in the first place.